# What is the main difference between Amazon S3 and Amazon EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For web Sites/Applications and eCommerce,
which storage solution is more desirable and Why ?

Im very new to Amazon Cloud services I need some direction here.

Comment: this question might be more suitable for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok, can you provide recommendation, that would be more useful for thanks?

Comment: THANKS Alfasin - I didnt know about that site. Im only new to SO.

Comment: I really would recommend that you *not* ask this question on webmasters. You'll receive a poor reception there as well, for the same reason. Stack Exchange sites, as a whole, aren't suited for this kind of A-B question.

Comment: Then could you recommend a website that does, Im guessing QnA websites are all about sharing of Knowledge ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

S3 likes network storage, you can access it with web api
ebs likes hard disk, you can access it in your ec2
you can also see, 
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-amazon-s3-and-amazon-ebs/

Answer (score 0):

EBS is meant for transactional data and S3 for everything else. In EBS you can have static IP which is required when we use database access etc.